# Immutable builder and updater

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, immutability, expression-trees

There aren't enough questions about creating immutable objects... so why not try it again with another approach. This time, it's a builder that maps properties to constructor parameters. Properties are selected via the `With` method that also expects a new value for the parameter. Constructor parameters must match properties so it's primarily for DTOs that follow this pattern. `Build` tries to find that constructor and creates the object.

```
// I need this primarily for the left-join of optional parameters.
internal class IgnoreCase : IEquatable<string>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(string other) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(Value, other);
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is IgnoreCase ic && Equals(ic.Value);
    public override int GetHashCode() => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Value);
    public static explicit operator IgnoreCase(string value) => new IgnoreCase { Value = value };
}

public class ImmutableBuilder<T>
{
    private readonly IList<(MemberExpression Selector, object Value)> _selectors = new List<(MemberExpression Selector, object Value)>();

    public ImmutableBuilder<T> With<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector, TProperty value)
    {
        _selectors.Add(((MemberExpression)selector.Body, value));
        return this;
    }

    public T Build()
    {
        var ctors =
            from ctor in typeof(T).GetConstructors()
            let parameters = ctor.GetParameters()
            // Join parameters and values by parameter order. 
            // The ctor requires them sorted but they might be initialized in any order.
            let requiredParameterValues =
                from parameter in parameters.Where(p => !p.IsOptional)
                join selector in _selectors on (IgnoreCase)parameter.Name equals (IgnoreCase)selector.Selector.Member.Name
                select selector.Value
            // Get optional parameters if any.
            let optionalParameterValues =
                from parameter in parameters.Where(p => p.IsOptional)
                join selector in _selectors on (IgnoreCase)parameter.Name equals (IgnoreCase)selector.Selector.Member.Name into s
                from selector in s.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select selector.Value
            // Make sure all required parameters are specified.
            where requiredParameterValues.Count() == parameters.Where(p => !p.IsOptional).Count()
            select (ctor, requiredParameterValues, optionalParameterValues);

        var theOne = ctors.Single();
        return (T)theOne.ctor.Invoke(theOne.requiredParameterValues.Concat(theOne.optionalParameterValues).ToArray());
    }
}

public static class Immutable<T>
{
    public static ImmutableBuilder<T> Builder => new ImmutableBuilder<T>();
}
```

In case we already have an immutable type and want to *modify* it by changing just some values, the `ImmutableHelper` can be used. It also provides the `With` method expecting a new value. Then matches it and other properties with the constructor and uses origianl values as defaults and for the specified property the new value.

```
public static class ImmutableHelper
{
    public static T With<T, TProperty>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector, TProperty value)
    {
        var comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member.Name;
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        var propertyNames =
            properties
                .Select(x => x.Name)
                // A hash-set is convenient for name matching in the next step.
                .ToImmutableHashSet(comparer);

        // Find the constructor that matches property names.
        var ctors =
            from ctor in typeof(T).GetConstructors()
            where propertyNames.IsProperSupersetOf(ctor.GetParameters().Select(x => x.Name))
            select ctor;

        var theOne = ctors.Single(); // There can be only one match.        

        var parameters =
            from parameter in theOne.GetParameters()
            join property in properties on (IgnoreCase)parameter.Name equals (IgnoreCase)property.Name
            // They definitely match so no comparer is necessary.
            // Use either the new value or the current one.
            select property.Name == propertyName ? value : property.GetValue(obj);

        return (T)theOne.Invoke(parameters.ToArray());
    }
}
```

#### Example

This is how it can be used:

```
void Main()
{
    var person = 
        Immutable<Person>
            .Builder
            .With(x => x.FirstName, "Jane")
            .With(x => x.LastName, null)
            //.With(x => x.NickName, "JD") // Optional
            .Build();

    person.With(x => x.LastName, "Doe").Dump();
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string nickName = null)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        NickName = nickName;
    }

    // This ctor should confuse the API.
    public Person(string other) { }

    public string FirstName { get; }

    public string LastName { get; }

    public string NickName { get; }

    // This property should confuse the API too.
    public string FullName => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
}
```

---

What do you say? Crazy? Insane? I like it? Let's improve it?

Comment: This has a use case for building controllers and what not that have dozens of parameters. Does this also work with optional ctr arguments?

Comment: @dfhwze it doesn't... but it definitelly could... and should.

Comment: Ok ... so let's improve it! :p

Comment: @dfhwze done! ;-] at least the main builder can do this now.

Comment: As I said to a few ppl today, I'm out of votes, but this is excellent stuff. Your pace is insane o_0

Comment: I like the `With` extensions method that helps to create modified copies of mutable types. However I didn't get the use case of the `ImmutableBuilder`.. Why not just calling the constructor?

Comment: @JanDotNet yeah, this idea wasn't the best one especially that it required all parameters. I removed this constraint. It now allows to update any property/field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `IList<>` where you should use `ICollection<>`. I've rarely encountered a scenario where `IList<>` actually needs to be used. The `ICollection<>` interface has most of the list's methods, but without everything related to indexing, which you don't use anyway. It's not that big of a deal, but I think it's good knowledge.

---

When you search for constructor parameters, I think you should match on parameter types in addition of parameter names. The reason behind this is that this that parameter types with names are guaranteed to be unique, where parameter names could not. For example (it's not a great one, but it's a case that would make your code potentially crash)

```
class Foobar
{

    public Foobar(string a, int b)
    {
    }

    public Foobar(string a, double b)
    {
    }

}
```

---

One problem I see with the `Immutable<T>` class is that I wouldn't expect a `static` property to return a new reference every time I call it. I've been trying to find another example in the .NET framework of when this happens, and... I couldn't. I would change it for a method named something like `CreateBuilder()` or something like that, this way it's clear that we are using a new builder every time we call the method.

---

I think the `Immutable<>` type is misleading. When seeing this, I'd expect being able to use it to make some mutable type immutable (however that would be done), but that's not what it does. As a matter of fact, most of your code doesn't rely on the `T` type to be immutable, which makes me think a tweak or two could make your tool work on mutable types too. In that sense, claiming it's an `ImmutableBuilder` is kind of wrong, it's a builder that works on immutable types, but on mutable types too.

---

According to comments, your `With` method in `ImmutableHelper` creates a copy of the object with a changed parameter, which is alright considering it doesn't modify the immutable type. What I think could be improved is a similar method with the signature `static T With<T, TProperty>(this T obj, IEnmerable<(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector, TProperty value)>)`, so that if you want to modify more than one field in the object you could do so without having to create a copy of the object every time.

Comment: About the last paragraph... this will go into production (after I made it match parameter types too) because let's say you have an immutable type `Uri` with such a constructor as `scheme, authority, path, query, fragment` and you just want to _change_ its `scheme` from _nothing_ (relative uri) to `http` and maybe add a `fragment`. It's mutch easier and reliable to do this with `With(x => x.Property, value)` and let the framework handle other values than copy all the values yourself... and I once made that mistake of forgetting one of them... I was chasing the bug for 3h :-[

Comment: @t3chb0t But by doing this you break everything that is expected from an immutable type. If another developer uses the `Uri` class, he/she will expect it to be immutable. If you happen to use your method somewhere in the code, debugging for this other person will be much more hellish than otherwise. You could use a `Copy` method then change the necessary fields or something else, maybe.

Comment: @t3chb0t Although I understand the bug you've had, it's a tricky bug to find because it's kind of unexpected. I just don't think mutating immutable types is the right solution. Otherwise, maybe your `With` method could create a new copy of the object

Comment: Oh, you mean this... yes! It is creating a new copy. The first class is just an initializer and the extension `ImmutableHelper.With` copies values into a new object. I probably should have put quotes around _updater_.

Comment: @t3chb0t oohhh. Let me edit my answer then.

Comment: Actually there is (at least) one type that has a `static` property returning new values everytime... but the authors admit that it was a mistake (they write about it in the book about framework design... I don't remember title of it right now)... it's the _famous_ `DateTime.(Utc)Now`.

Comment: @t3chb0t yes, that's a good example. Although, as you stated, it's probably a pattern that wouldn't be repeated today.

Answer (score 1):

*(self-answer)*

---

The idea for not-using the constructor is indeed insane but... since it's possible I kept it in the new version too. I changed the name of this tool to `DtoUpdater`. It now can collect updates for multiple properties that at the end have to be `Commit`ed. Parameters are now matched with members not only by name but also by type and it picks the constructor with the most parameters ana matching properties. I created this helper for updating *simple* DTOs and they usually have only one constructor initializing all properties so I think its current *complexity* is sufficient for most use-cases.

This version also no longer forces the user to specify all values that a constructor requires. I think that this new functionality now makes this utility in certain situations  more useful than using the construtor... if it allows `default` values of course.

```
public static class DtoUpdater
{
    public static DtoUpdater<T> For<T>() => new DtoUpdater<T>(default);

    public static DtoUpdater<T> Update<T>(this T obj) => new DtoUpdater<T>(obj);
}

public class DtoUpdater<T>
{
    private readonly T _obj;

    private readonly ICollection<(MemberInfo Member, object Value)> _updates = new List<(MemberInfo Member, object Value)>();

    public DtoUpdater(T obj) => _obj = obj;

    public DtoUpdater<T> With<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> update, TProperty value)
    {
        _updates.Add((((MemberExpression)update.Body).Member, value));
        return this;
    }

    public T Commit()
    {
        var members =
            from member in typeof(T).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(m => m is PropertyInfo || m is FieldInfo)
            select (member.Name, Type: (member as PropertyInfo)?.PropertyType ?? (member as FieldInfo)?.FieldType);

        members = members.ToList();

        // Find the ctor that matches most properties.
        var ctors =
            from ctor in typeof(T).GetConstructors()
            let parameters = ctor.GetParameters()
            from parameter in parameters
            join member in members
                on
                new
                {
                    Name = parameter.Name.AsIgnoreCase(),
                    Type = parameter.ParameterType
                }
                equals
                new
                {
                    Name = member.Name.AsIgnoreCase(),
                    Type = member.Type
                }
            orderby parameters.Length descending
            select ctor;

        var theOne = ctors.First();

        // Join parameters and values by parameter order.
        // The ctor requires them sorted but they might be initialized in any order.
        var parameterValues =
            from parameter in theOne.GetParameters()
            join update in _updates on parameter.Name.AsIgnoreCase() equals update.Member.Name.AsIgnoreCase() into x
            from update in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select update.Value ?? GetMemberValueOrDefault(parameter.Name);

        return (T)theOne.Invoke(parameterValues.ToArray());
    }

    private object GetMemberValueOrDefault(string memberName)
    {
        if (_obj == null) return default;

        // There is for sure only one member with that name.
        switch (typeof(T).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(m => m.Name.AsIgnoreCase().Equals(memberName)))
        {
            case PropertyInfo p: return p.GetValue(_obj);
            case FieldInfo f: return f.GetValue(_obj);
            default: return default; // Makes the compiler very happy.
        }
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEquatable<string> AsIgnoreCase(this string str) => (IgnoreCase)str;

    private class IgnoreCase : IEquatable<string>
    {
        private IgnoreCase(string value) => Value = value;
        private string Value { get; }
        public bool Equals(string other) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(Value, other);
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is IgnoreCase ic && Equals(ic.Value);
        public override int GetHashCode() => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Value);
        public static explicit operator IgnoreCase(string value) => new IgnoreCase(value);
    }
}
```

I hid the `IgnoreCase` helper behind a new extension:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEquatable<string> AsIgnoreCase(this string str) => (IgnoreCase)str;

    private class IgnoreCase : IEquatable<string>
    {
        private IgnoreCase(string value) => Value = value;
        private string Value { get; }
        public bool Equals(string other) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(Value, other);
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is IgnoreCase ic && Equals(ic.Value);
        public override int GetHashCode() => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(Value);
        public static explicit operator IgnoreCase(string value) => new IgnoreCase(value);
    }
}
```

The new API can now be used like this:

```
public class DtoBuilderTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Can_create_and_update_object()
    {
        var person =
            DtoUpdater
                .For<Person>()
                .With(x => x.FirstName, "Jane")
                .With(x => x.LastName, null)
                //.With(x => x.NickName, "JD") // Optional
                .Commit();

        Assert.Equal("Jane", person.FirstName);
        Assert.Null(person.LastName);
        Assert.Null(person.NickName);

        person =
            person
                .Update()
                .With(x => x.LastName, "Doe")
                .With(x => x.NickName, "JD")
                .Commit();

        Assert.Equal("Jane", person.FirstName);
        Assert.Equal("Doe", person.LastName);
        Assert.Equal("JD", person.NickName);
    }

    private class Person
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string nickName = null)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            NickName = nickName;
        }

        // This ctor should confuse the API.
        public Person(string other) { }

        public string FirstName { get; }

        public string LastName { get; }

        public string NickName { get; set; }

        // This property should confuse the API too.
        public string FullName => $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
    }
}
```

Comment: This _update/commit_ pattern makes me think we can tune this up to be used as a batch updater with support for multi-level change tracking/reverting implementing _IEditableObject_, _IChangeTracking_ and _IRevertibleChangeTracking_ (up-vote pending btw)

Comment: @dfhwze haha don't even think of it. Two more refactoring rounds and it can fly to the moon ;-P

Comment: I might ask a follow-up question about it in the weekend o_0 But change tracking is not that trivial /o\

Comment: @dfhwze I'm not so sure we need all this tracking and undo logic. This demo doesn't show that but usually when you modify an immutable, you pass it so some deeper scope. When it returns, you pick up the previous version for this scope and continue from here. At leat this is how I mostly use immutables. They are convenient to update and use in a new context for a moment. Although it might be useful for debugging.

Comment: We don't need it for this use case, I want to stea.. 'borrow' your code to make a change tracking API :p Basically, I want your immutable code for my mutable stuff. That's it, I'm no longer making any sense at all ... I'm off to bed, see ya.

Comment: @dfhwze oh, now I get it. then please do. I could use one of those too. So we'll be borrowing from each other haha